# Share optical drive over lan

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive

Is there any way that you can create an optical drive server so that you can share like an audio-cd on a webserver without converting.

Situation: School with new Chromebooks.

Comment: If your "server" is a Windows-based server then you should be able to share the drive (right click the drive letter and "Share"). This should be accessible through Windows, Mac and Linux OSes through an SMB address (`smb://...`) but not sure on Chromebook... If Chromebook can connect via SMB (`smb://<server>/<cd_share>`) then you should be able to connect... would it not be easier to rip the audio files to MP3 and make them available??? Perhaps rip them to a web server share and have them as downloadable files from a web page?

Comment: if it's mounted as a share, all you'll see would be the 'file placeholders' - Track01.cda etc rather than the actual playable audio. Neither Mac nor Windows can play from a remote .cda file, idk about ChromeOS.